# C# WPF, How to hide hard coded password?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an internal only Helpdesk program that has admin access to servers on the private network to pull logs, reboot hung servers, and perform other various admin tasks..

Rather than giving admin access to a significant number level 1 helpdesk users across hundreds of servers, my program runs under a single admin account, which **access to this program is protected under a AD group**, and **launched only on a single Windows server via Citrix published app.** So access to run the app is protected, but the password for the account with server access is hardcoded in the code using securestring.
I am not an expert level programmer. Just an advanced sysadmin with enough knowledge to do more things to accomplish my needs.
I know securestring is not recommended anymore, but i dont have the advanced knowledge to implement another password encryption solution without some help.

This is the code being used in my C# WPF app..

```
secureString pass = new NetworkCredential("", "hardcodedpassword").SecurePassword;
strCmdText = "command to be run here"

 Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
                process.StartInfo.UserName = "Helpdesk1";
                process.StartInfo.Password = pass;
                process.StartInfo.Domain = "Domain1";
                process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                pass.Dispose();
```

I also have some users who are not very technical, but need to perform some limited tasks, like logging off stuck users from servers where you need admin access. That is why i do not want to assign Admin to these individual AD accounts. Having them access a single tool with the required access running on a single windows server solves that problem compared to giving all these users direct server admin access. So bottom line is I just want to be able to at least hide password in the code at least at the minimum, fully understanding its not the best approach. Thank you for the help!

Comment: this definitely sounds like a bad idea. you really should delegate the users with the correct role/permissions as needed. there's tools that would help with that on the fly.

Comment: _"Rather than giving admin access to a significant number level 1 helpdesk users"_ - so what you do instead is giving them access to a jumper which makes it impossible to track who did what? I guess not. Right?

Comment: I dont want to give users direct admin access to servers under their own AD account, where they could then access the servers from their own machines or anywhere, and do anything they want. Giving access through the app under a single account, with only access to perform specific tasks within this app prevents that.

Comment: TL;DR: you _can't_ - at some point, the program needs to have direct access to the unencrypted password. which is when an attacker _can_ grab it. period. also: "Giving access through the app under a single account prevents that." - no. giving _every use one account_ which only they have the password for prevents that.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann.. no your misunderstanding my comment. i meant giving access through the app only lets them perform the admin tasks i want them to use. If i gave each user direct admin access via their AD account, they could then bypass the app and do whatever they like on the servers.

Comment: I also have some users who are not very technical, but need to perform some limited tasks, like logging off stuck users from servers where you need admin access. That is why i do not want to assign Admin to these individual AD accounts. Having them access a single tool with the required access running on a single windows server solves that problem compared to giving all these users direct server admin access. So bottom line is I just want to be able to at least hide password in the code at least at the minimum, fully understanding its not the best approach.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166401/hashing-a-securestring-in-c

Comment: thats why you give an user that only has to do XYZ an account that only _can_ do XYZ. basically like Daniel already said in the first comment. nobody said anything about "giving the users direct server admin access". but about "giving every user their own credentials _they can put into your app_"